# How to filter a character stream from an application using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

A powershell question: I want to extract each line in a character stream produced by an application that matches a certain pattern which in pseudo-code would be something like this:
PS> `<a_ps_command> <the_application_command_for_outputting_the_text_stream> | <my_filter > output_file.txt`

In my case the application is a CM-tool that outputs the change history of a source file and the (psuedo)pattern should be something like: 
`<a couple of numbers><a name><a time stamp><a line of characters>`

Cheers,
Christian

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The filtering cmdlet in PowerShell is `Where-Object` (aliases `Where` and `?`).  You simply pass the output of the SCM command into it.  You then use $_ to represent the current line and test against it e.g.:

```
tf hist .\Settings.StyleCop /i /stopafter:20 | Where {$_ -match '^\d+.*?Hack'}
```

The `-Match` operator is used to compare the current line of output against a regex.  I use `^\d+` to filter out the first two lines of `tf hist` output (which are formatting strings) and then I search on the text `Hack` anywhere else on the line (looking for it in comments for instance).  You would modify and enhance the regex to meet your needs.

Answer (score 3):

As a fan of operators I have to add third answer :]

You don't need to use cmdlets and piping. Just use operators like `-match` or `-like`:

```
PS> (ipconfig) -match 'ipv6'
PS> (ipconfig) -like '*ipv*'
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at Select-String.  Powershell's answer to grep.